# How to restrict Ansible's setup module (gather_facts) to only retrieve the server's hostname, for example?=?

Tags: ansible

For strictly the purpose of speeding up the Ansible flow, I need just a few details to be retrieved from the host. The information that I need most often is the ansible_hostname, to make sure I'm landing on the correct host as I have a dynamic DNS.
Under which gather_subset does the hostname fall?
This is about limiting the data that is gathered from the host, as opposed to the `filter` option.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is possible to restrict the information gathered using gather_facts. Please check the docs of the [ansible setup module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/setup_module.html) on how to restrict information based on various subsets.

```
- hosts: my_target
  gather_facts:no

  pre_tasks:
    - setup:
        gather_subset: 'network'

  tasks:
    - debug: var=ansible_hostname
```

The available subsets from which the information can be gathered from is as follows

> all, all_ipv4_addresses, all_ipv6_addresses, apparmor, architecture,
> caps, chroot, cmdline, date_time, default_ipv4, default_ipv6, devices,
> distribution, distribution_major_version, distribution_release,
> distribution_version, dns, effective_group_ids, effective_user_id,
> env, facter, fips, hardware, interfaces, is_chroot, kernel, local,
> lsb, machine, machine_id, mounts, network, ohai, os_family, pkg_mgr,
> platform, processor, processor_cores, processor_count, python,
> python_version, real_user_id, selinux, service_mgr,
> ssh_host_key_dsa_public, ssh_host_key_ecdsa_public,
> ssh_host_key_ed25519_public, ssh_host_key_rsa_public,
> ssh_host_pub_keys, ssh_pub_keys, system, system_capabilities,
> system_capabilities_enforced, user, user_dir, user_gecos, user_gid,
> user_id, user_shell, user_uid, virtual, virtualization_role,
> virtualization_type

These values are mentioned in the error, when we provide an unsupported value.

The documentation mentions only a few values, between which are "min" and "any" which are not mentioned in the error.

This is a known bug:
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/47603